# Why does GDB not remove convenience variables?

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

Per the documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html), gdb states:

> Function: gdb.set_convenience_variable (name, value)
>   [...] If value is None, then the convenience variable is removed.

but when I execute

```py
gdb.set_convenience_variable('foo', 1)
gdb.set_convenience_variable('foo', None)
```

a `show conv` in the gdb shell shows `$foo = void`. The expected behavior is that gdb will remove the variable completely. In a custom command I use uuids as variable names on the gdb-side for holding intermediate expression results (to avoid name clashes) so having these variables stick around is not ideal. I did not see anything about this in the gdb [bug tracker](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=SUSPENDED&bug_status=WAITING&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&f0=OP&f1=OP&f10=OP&f11=OP&f12=product&f13=component&f14=alias&f15=short_desc&f17=content&f18=CP&f19=CP&f2=product&f20=OP&f21=OP&f22=product&f23=component&f24=alias&f25=short_desc&f27=content&f28=CP&f29=CP&f3=component&f4=alias&f5=short_desc&f7=content&f8=CP&f9=CP&j1=OR&j11=OR&j21=OR&o12=substring&o13=substring&o14=substring&o15=substring&o16=substring&o17=matches&o2=substring&o22=substring&o23=substring&o24=substring&o25=substring&o26=substring&o27=matches&o3=substring&o4=substring&o5=substring&o6=substring&o7=matches&product=gdb&query_format=advanced&short_desc=convenience%20variable&short_desc_type=anywordssubstr&v12=convenience&v13=convenience&v14=convenience&v15=convenience&v16=convenience&v17=%22convenience%22&v2=gdb&v22=variable&v23=variable&v24=variable&v25=variable&v26=variable&v27=%22variable%22&v3=gdb&v4=gdb&v5=gdb&v6=gdb&v7=%22gdb%22) and going through the code it does not appear there is a method to actually **remove** a convenience variable - just set it to void ([here](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/502c64b9ac12cf2a35d3cb55c51e2eefd33a2494/gdb/value.c#L2346)).

Answer (score 2):

I concur. The [function to create internal variables](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/502c64b9ac12cf2a35d3cb55c51e2eefd33a2494/gdb/value.c#L2025) shows why this was not implemented right away: this function simply prepends to the existing list of internal variables. Removing an element from such a singly-linked list is not completely trivial since you have to splice the according elements as anybody who has ever implemented a singly linked list can testify but it is not hard either... let's see [what the maintainers say](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25287). Please consider filing such bug reports yourself if you find such problems!

Comment: Well, literally nothing happened to that bug report since I reported it... so I'd like to refine my last sentence to "Please consider filing such bug reports yourself if you find such problems if the project has a proven history of taking care of such reports!" ;)